# WordPress - MySQL server has gone away

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, database, timeout

I have a WordPress install on a dedicated server with decent memory (upwards of 8GB).

The WordPress install includes many plugins - 50 active plugins. Most important to note is the [WPML](http://wpml.org/) plugin to make WordPress multilingual. The theme is [Weaver II Pro](http://pro.weavertheme.com/).

The stack is LAMP - CentOS 6.3, Apache 2.4.4, Percona MySQL, PHP-FPM.

I have been quite stupid, and didn't set up a test or staging server.

Everything was running fine till I updated to WordPress 3.8, and also updated several plugins at the same time.

I didn't pay attention at the time, but all my widgets got messed up, and so did any sort of navigation etc.

I enabled error_log for a bit, i.e.

```
ini_set('log_errors',TRUE);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/error_log.txt');
```

This resulted in an immense file - basically the error_log grows by about a GB every 4 minutes or so.

The primary error I found in the error log was database server disconnect, better known as

> MySQL server has gone away

As suggested at [Rackspace](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-to-change-the-mysql-timeout-on-a-server), I edited my.cnf to add

```
wait_timeout = 60
```

Didn't help.

Also added caching to my.cnf

```
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_limit = 8M
query_cache_size = 512M
```

Didn't help.

(and yes, I restarted mysql every time I edited my.cnf)

Also tried the method [suggested here](http://www.techmesto.com/solving-wordpress-mysql-gone-error/):
In wp-db.php
before

```
$this->select( $this->dbname, $this->dbh );
```

I added

```
$this->query("set session wait_timeout=600" );
```

Didn't help.

I'm at my wit's end. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does setting max_allowed_packet to something higher help you (in your my.cnf)? 
Like: max_allowed_packet      = 16M

Comment: Did the trick :-)

Comment: For people getting here from Google: If changing the `max_allowed_packet` size or `wait_timeout` amount doesn't fix it, check your memory usage. I was getting the same error and it was being caused by my server running out of memory. I added a 1GB swap file and that fixed it.